# Fundamental solution of linear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I struggle to understand what the fundamental solution is supposed to be.
Specifically it's about a linear system of homogen ODEs with constant coefficents of the form: $\dot{\textbf{F}}=\textbf{AF}$ where $\textbf{F},\dot{\textbf{F}}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^n}, \textbf{A} \in \mathbb{R} ^{n \times n}$.

In the lecture we were told $\Phi(t) = Exp(\textbf{A}t) : \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R} ^{n \times n} $ is the fundamental solution of the system, since symbolically $\Phi'(t)=\textbf{A}\Phi(t)$. With the definition I see this makes sense but why is the solution a matrix instead of a vector? I really don't understand the relatonship between the fundamental solution and $\textbf{F}$ nor what the fundamental solution even is? (Calculus in Engineering is sometimes a bit short with explanations...)

Comment: I suggest you take a simple example with $\dot{x},\dot{y}$ to see how it all fits together. There is no point in adopting sophisticated notation until you have grasped clearly what is going on.

Comment: Maybe, it was a misprint of $\Phi\left(t\right) = \exp\left(\mathbf{A}t\right)\color{#f00}{\Phi\left(0\right)}$ which omitted the vector $\color{#f00}{\Phi\left(0\right)}$.

Comment: I don't really think it's a misprint as it was made clear that $\Phi(t)$ is a function $\Phi(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} ^{n \times n} $. Is it maybe something like a basis of the solution space?

It probably won't be on the exam like this anyway because it takes too long to calculate by hand, but it's used to deduce solutions to other equations but I don't even really understand what this is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subtle point of terminology.  The solution to the first-order, linear, homogeneous system $\dot{f}(t) = A\,f(t)$ where $f,\dot{f} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has the solution

$$
f(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k f_k(t)
$$

where $c_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f_k: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$   $\forall k$.  In others words, the solution to the above linear system of dimension $n$ is a linear combination of $n$ independent solutions (ideally).  We can re-write the summation in linear algebra notation as
$$
f(t) = \Phi(t)\,c
$$
where 
$$
\Phi(t) = [f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n]\quad\mbox{and}\quad c=[c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n]^{\intercal}.
$$
Therefore, just as $y = \exp(x)$ may be called a fundamental solution to $\dot{y} = y$ as it encompasses all of the solution's behavior up to a multiplicative scalar determined by initial conditions, the matrix of solutions $\Phi(t)$ is sometimes called the fundamental solution to the linear system $\dot{f}(t) = A\,f(t)$ as it encompasses all of the solutions' behaviors up to a multiplicative vector determined by initial conditions.